# Firebase Analytics Funnel why no option to filter by event parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

There is absolutely no option to do so in Firebase Console or am I just not seeing it?

[image]

What is the point of having all these parameters if I can't use them?

```
screen_view

(app)

when a screen transition occurs and any of the following criteria are met:
 
No screen was previously set
The new screen name differs from the previous screen name
The new screen-class name differs from the previous screen-class name
The new screen id differs from the previous screen id
firebase_screen, firebase_screen_class, firebase_screen_id, firebase_previous_screen, firebase_previous_class, firebase_previous_id, engagement_time_msec
```

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate the parameters in the Analytics platform to be able to use them, otherwise you will only be able to see them on BigQuery if you have connected these two platforms.

Link Google Analytics 4 properties to Firebase: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

How do events and parameters work with Google Analytics 4 properties: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/tag-guide

GA4 BigQuery Export: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en

Comment: Can you elaborate what "the Analytics platform" is and how to activate parameters?